# Thread 1: signal SIGABRT - AppDelegate.h

Tags: ios, objective-c

```
//
//  main.m
//  Journey
//
//  Created by Julian Buscema on 2014-07-13.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Julian Buscema. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

#import "AppDelegate.h"

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    @autoreleasepool {
        return UIApplicationMain(argc, argv, nil, NSStringFromClass([AppDelegate class]));
    }
}
```

When I try running my application, my main.m opens up and the "return UIApplicationMain...." line is highlighted in green saying thread 1: signal SIGABRT. I googled it and it says that it has to do with my AppDelegate.h file but which part of it?

Here it is:

```
//
//  AppDelegate.h
//  Journey
//
//  Created by Julian Buscema on 2014-07-13.
//  Copyright (c) 2014 Julian Buscema. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

@end
```

Comment: P.S. there's no errors or warnings in my project.

Comment: See http://raywenderlich.com/10209/my-app-crashed-now-what-part-1 to learn how to debug and find the issue.

Comment: Your code is all right. Please show us AppDelegate.m file.

Comment: @rmaddy I'm very confused because there are many types of problems in that forum... I went through my outlet and this is what I found: http://pastebin.com/6fVDHVXX

Comment: @borisy http://pastebin.com/VcL5XM1U

Comment: @Julian thanks, are you using any Storyboard?

Comment: @borisy http://imgur.com/PpGziHX

Comment: It must be a problem with a link from your first view controller in your storyboard. I suppose that you have linked something to a @property IBOUlet named 'username' but then you've deleted this property without remove the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error says `this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key username.`

Something is not right with element named `username.` Did you create outlets from Storyboard to your ViewController? If you you did, are you renamed property in ViewController?

Try right clicking on UITextField and check outlets. Empty white circle means your outlet is broken, it must be white.

Comment: http://imgur.com/xlrXo0K I put both of the images in there of both of the username text fields. So I'm not sure what I should do after the error is found... I'm sorry for all the questions.

Comment: @Julian don't be sorry. You have 3 scenes there. Please do the same right clicking check on each one.

Comment: Thanks for being so patient, I really appreciate it. And the 3rd scene is blank, it's just an image. Here's my ViewController's: http://pastebin.com/zEaLVF3X, http://pastebin.com/Gx5wYktQ

Comment: I see 2 outlets from image. One called username and second called usernameField. Delete outlet called "username". In storyboard hover your mouth over it and click on "x" button. I see IBOutlet called usernameField in your ViewController. There is no property called "username". In Storyboard you're referencing property called "username" that is not exist in your ViewController any more.

Comment: Ok I deleted the username reference but now I get a new crash reason. http://imgur.com/r2GxpG4

Comment: It's not crash. Click on "play" button. You're in a debugging mode because of the breakpoint.

Comment: http://tinypic.com/player.php?v=258wn85%3E&s=8#.U8gqXY1dXno This is what keeps happening

Comment: I'm on iOS right now and can't watch video because it's require Flash

Comment: Ahh ok, well basically it runs fine, then I go to click on the text field, the app freezes, then everything turns black, so I go to my code and it's this screen again imgur.com/r2GxpG4.

Comment: Click on blue triangle on bottom to disable breakpoint. Then run again.