# How do i fix xcode 6.3's black screen error?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

So when I try to run my app on xcode, it just shows the splashscreen, and then proceeds to show me a black page. I have already reset content and settings, however when i do so, it sends me to the line "class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate {". I have also clicked on "Active breakpoints" and no luck. I have restarted xcode and that has also not done anything. After doing this i deleted some files in the derived data folder but its done nothing. Please help!

Comment: This isn't enough information to diagnose your problem. How are you setting up your initial view controller (in code, in a storyboard)? What do you mean by, "reset content and settings"? Did you get a crash before you did that?

Comment: Yes, my storyboard is my main view.

Answer (score 0):

Click the storyboard's initial View Controller. Make sure that there's an arrow pointing into it (and its set as initial view controller). Next thing is to check if the backgroundColor is `[UIColor whiteColor]`.

Answer (score 0):

Its why I moved away from storyboards. This commonly happens with the loose coupling between xml layout file (nib storyboards) and your  controller classes. You may have a miss-spelling in an outlet. Orphaned outlets. Look at the outlets view in the designer. Its very easy to do with code that doesn't compile before runtime.

Similar to this issue.
[Thread 1: signal SIGABRT - AppDelegate.h](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24810540/thread-1-signal-sigabrt-appdelegate-h)